# a class variable having the same type of Class itself

Tags: class, oop, object, design-patterns

Today I saw a class similar to this at my work place:

```
public class A {
    private Map<String, A> myMap = Maps.newHashMap();
}
```

The code compiles, works and does what it suppose to do. But it can be refactored to different design. But I don't understand why this design was chosen.

You can do silly things like this:

`this.myMap.get("x").myMap.get("x").myMap.get("x");`

My question:

Is there a really a good situation where we need to apply such design? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tree comes to mind immediately: a node contains a list of nodes.

A person has children, which are persons too, and who can have children too.

Comment: To expand, this probably makes sense: `public class Person{ Map<string, Person> relationshipMap }` where `relationshipMap` is the collection of people, and the string describes the relationship (mother, father, child, etc)